# send an array of bytes by NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I want to communicate between an ARM and a Smartphone (I have an Xperia Sola and a Acer S500)
(with my ARM I've a PN532)

everywhere I've seen, people send NDEF messages to a tag or for beam anything...

In my case I just want to send an array of Bytes. the goal of this project is to send a file to the arm, so I gonna send my file cut.

for the moment my ARM read and write on DESFire tag's so i would user the isodep class because I see that we can send an array of bytes with this method : public byte[] transceive (byte[] data)

can you help me to know what I'm needing to do ?

Thx a lot

Comment: So any good reason you do not want to wrap your file parts in an NDEF message? You can use the  UnknownRecord which is very simple and essentially have a byte payload.

Answer (score 0):

Point-to-point communication in Android is not quite general purpose. You can only send one message per touch, and you have to use the 'beam' protocols: NDEF push or SNEP. So if your device (whats' an 'ARM') implements one of those, you can send single messages. This is very different from talking to a card/tag with `IsoDep`, etc., so those are not applicable. Unless your 'ARM' is running in some sort of card emulation mode, of course.